# How to count and filter based off of a tables subtotal values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple table of documents by type and size:

```
Name  | DocType| Size
Lorem | Word   | 55
Ipsum | Excel  | 32
Doler | Access | 150
Sit   | Word   | 40
Amet  | Excel  | 60
```

I am trying to perform some very simple operations like count and filter, but based off the subtotals for a category and not individual/totals.

Specifically I am looking to return a single number for a KPI report that shows the number of Doctypes where the subtotal for the Doctype is <100 (in this case returning 2 for Word + Excel). In a similar vein I am looking to return a single number for a KPI report that shows the number of Doctypes where the count of that Doctype in the table is < 2 (in this case returning 1 for Access).

However I cannot figure out how to build these formulas as I am not sure how to perform the filtering based off of the subtotal of Doctype instead of evaluating the filter against the individual rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to summarize data first, and then evaluate the summary. There are many ways to do it; one standard technique is to use SUMMARIZE function.

Create a measure:

```
Size < 100 =
VAR Doc_Summary =
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[DocType], "Total Size", SUM ( Data[Size] ) )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Doc_Summary, [Total Size] < 100 ) )
```

where "Data" is the name of the table I used (change to your table name).

Here, we first group data by DocType, and sum up sizes per each group. Then, we filter the summary to keep only groups where sum of size meets our criteria, and count the rows in the resulting table.

Similarly, create another measure:

```
Count < 2 =
VAR Doc_Summary =
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[DocType], "Total Count", COUNT ( [DocType] ) )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Doc_Summary, [Total Count] < 2 ) )
```

It works the same way.

Result:

[image]